# This specific code just refuses to compile?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, c++, compile

I've been working on some software to do REALLY basic composition of music.
Here's my code so far:

```
#include "notes_sharps.h"

int notes[] = {NOTE_B0,NOTE_C1,NOTE_D1,NOTE_E1,NOTE_F1,NOTE_G1,NOTE_A1,NOTE_B1,NOTE_C2,NOTE_D2,NOTE_E2,NOTE_F2,NOTE_G2,NOTE_A2,NOTE_B2,NOTE_C3,NOTE_D3,NOTE_E3,NOTE_F3,NOTE_G3,NOTE_A3,NOTE_B3,NOTE_C4,NOTE_D4,NOTE_E4,NOTE_F4,NOTE_G4,NOTE_A4,NOTE_B4,NOTE_C5,NOTE_D5,NOTE_E5,NOTE_F5,NOTE_G5,NOTE_A5,NOTE_B5,NOTE_C6,NOTE_D6,NOTE_E6,NOTE_F6,NOTE_G6,NOTE_A6,NOTE_B6,NOTE_C7,NOTE_D7,NOTE_E7,NOTE_F7,NOTE_G7,NOTE_A7,NOTE_B7,NOTE_C8,NOTE_D8};

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for(int i = 0; i < 51; i++){
    Serial.println("%i's sharp is %i",notes[i], notes[i]+(notes[i]*0.05937));  
  }
}

void loop(){}
```

This code just refuses to compile, no error messages, it simply leaves my computer dormant.
Here's the log:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avr-g++ -c -g -Os -w -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10604 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard C:\Users\anidude\AppData\Local\Temp\build38239327143584304.tmp\sharpscalc.cpp -o C:\Users\anidude\AppData\Local\Temp\build38239327143584304.tmp\sharpscalc.cpp.o`

Comment: Are you able to upload other codes to that unit?

Comment: That's a new usage of Serial.println... I think you're mixing Serial.println(const char *) and sprintf(char *buf, const char *format, ...)

Comment: @Jasmine I can run the example toneMelody without error.

Comment: I tried it and I got a very clear error message: "fatal error: notes_sharps.h: No such file or directory". If I create the missing file, another error message, just as clear: "error: no matching function for call to ‘HardwareSerial::println(const char [17], int&, double)’".

Comment: here's the actual notes_sharps.h file

http://pastebin.com/KVahvSNx

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that file. Seems like you just put it in the wrong place and the compiler can't see it. Very common problem with using libraries - http://www.arduino.cc/en/guide/libraries

Comment: It's not actually a library. It's just a file I wrote to make my actual program look cleaner.

Comment: That IS a library. It's a trivial library, but you need to install it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

As Majenko stated in the comments, your use of the println function is not valid as there exists no overload that takes char*, int, int as parameters.

You could get your program to work by replacing your println as following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 51; i++){
    Serial.print(notes[i]);
    Serial.print("'s sharp is ");
    Serial.println(notes[i]+(notes[i]*0.05937));
}
```